# CoCreateInstance called from one application fails to create instance of another application, if user is not admin

Tags: com, mfc, uac

I have an windows application(MFC-ATL-COM) "A", when launched, invokes app"B" using `CoCreateInstance()`.

When user is **Admin on Win7 system**, If app "A" is launched, even app "B" launches.
When user is a **standard Win7 user**, If app "A" is launched, app "B" **FAILS to launch**.

**Does `CoCreateInstance()` requires admin privileges to start another application from a parent application?** 
If so, how can we make sure even a standard user can internally initiate "B" using App "A".

Comment: Have you [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: It requires [Launch Permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not admin privileges exactly.